# How do you translate the English expression "Love drugs"?

Tags: translation

I thought about "farmaci sessuali" but that's not quite it. The shop exposing this is also selling things like oils and stuff. Any suggestion for a better translation?

---

ITALIAN: Pensavo a "farmaci sessuali" ma non è quello che cercavo. Il negozio che lo espone vende anche cose come oli eccetera. Suggerimenti per una traduzione migliore?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Can you clarify what  "love drugs" are? A Google search does not clarify what they're supposed to be

Comment: @DenisNardin: It's really hard to be more specific than this. actually the shop owner sells things like Viagra and some oil that is supposed to improve sexual performance. I'd now translate it as "Prodotti afrodisiaci" even though it's not a literal translation.

Comment: Can you give a definition, some examples, anything at all? Call me naive, but I don't know what you are speaking about. Viagra and the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a fixed translation for this, it relates to context. "Prodotto  afrodisiaco" is OK, and can actually apply to natural products that have (or are supposed to have) the same effects - such as Parmesan, Rhino horns and such. Even "Farmaco afrodisico" will do.
"Droga afrodisica" or "Droga erotica" has a more negative connotations, and possibly relates more to illegal drugs sold in night bars and discos.